# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: javascript

I have this message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null" while running the code below. Any help would be appreciated since I am not familiar with Javascript

Thank you in advance.

```js
function getUrlVars() {
    var arrGamePath = document.referrer;
    if(arrGamePath) {
        var reg = new RegExp("[/][a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[/]");
        var locale = reg.exec(arrGamePath) .toString();
        while (locale.indexOf("/") != -1) {
            locale = locale.replace("/", "");
        }
        return locale;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(getUrlVars()) {
    sCID = getUrlVars();
}
```

Comment: What does [`exec()` returns when no match is found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Return_value)? - **null**

Comment: Probably you need `/[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/.exec(document.referrer)`

Answer (score 2):

Your regex doesn't match and so returns `null`. `null` doesn't have a method `toString()`. So you should check for a match first and if it doesn't match, return `false` (or do whatever else you want to do - or change your regex so that it matches)

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var arrGamePath = document.referrer;
    if(arrGamePath) {
        var reg = new RegExp("[/][a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[/]");
        var matches = reg.exec(arrGamePath);
        if (!matches) return false;
        var locale = matches.toString();
        while (locale.indexOf("/") != -1) {
            locale = locale.replace("/", "");
        }
        return locale;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

if(typeof getUrlVars == 'function') {
    sCID = getUrlVars();
}
```

Also you are calling the function twice, once in your `if` line, ignoring the result:

```
if (getUrlVars())
```

and then if the `if` returns true, again. Just check if its type is a function instead.

Answer (score 0):

So this error is related to the null property which while you did not declare a `null` property, that is what you are getting back as @baao shared in the first answer.

So whenever you try to access a property under a value of null or undefined in JavaScript and try to read any property, call any function on it, you get an error message: cannot read properties of null, reading toString(), so that’s what’s going on behind the scenes that’s why you are getting an error.

You are trying to call `toString()` on `matches` which is currently `null` or was `null`.

In the modern world of TypeScript you could probably solve that like so:

```
const reg: null || string = new RegExp("[/][a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2,4}[/]");
```

And that might indicate, hey this `reg` variable is either a string or it might be null.